# Structure in objective c

Tags: objective-c

Getting errors when declaring this structure in objective c.

```
struct stRs232Struct*  pStruct;
pStruct->nMessageId = (int)uMessageId;
```

Error:Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is *stRs232Struct*? Is it your own structure? If yes then you actually should declare it somewhere. Something like this:

```
struct stRs232Struct {
    int nMessageId;
};
...
struct stRs232Struct* pStruct;
pStruct->nMessageId = (int)uMessageId;
...
```

If you have already declared it then you should check if the corresponding .h-file with its definition is included before usage.

Comment: I have included the header file.

Comment: @ron:And how about struct declaration? Have you declared it?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is warning you that it knows there's a type, but it doesn't know how that type looks like. You most likely have a forward declaration (`struct stRs232Struct;`) somewhere but you have not included the complete definition (`struct stRs232Struct { ... };`).